# What is the cause of multiple Security ID replacements?

Tags: hard-drive, filesystems

I ran a check disk as requested by a users machine and literally *thousands* of messages appeared towards the end stating

> "Replacing Invalid Security ID with Default ID for File 20****" and so on.

This laptop has once been dropped so I am aware that there may be a problem with the hard drive.

What I want to know is what causes the machine to have invalid security IDs in the file system?

Is it a virus that attacks the registry or indeed any virus?

or can it be multiple things?

Comment: Probably caused due to improper shutdowns

Comment: @Sathya I do recall the machine losing power during another scan disk operation it was a HP disk check program and the machine ran out of battery so could that be the cause?

Comment: it's highly possible - my system often has 2-3 unclean shutdowns  every week due to power failure and a routine chkdsk shows the same.

Comment: ah okay, I think this is just a problem caused by the battery power loss I was more concerned as I knew I needed to recover the hard drive before it died it wont boot windows now and keeps asking for chkdsk.